# Rent a car with unlimited mileage in southern France and drive to Croatia

Tags: france, car-rentals, borders, road-trips, croatia

I'm looking for a car rental agency in the south of France that allows me to drive to Croatia without extra mileage fees.

I only checked with subsidiaries of rental companies like Europcar, Sixt, Hertz, etc. in the southern region, and either they offer unlimited mileage but doesn't allow to drive to Croatia, either they charge (a lot) for extra mileage above 2 000 km.

So my question is : is it possible to find a rental company (local ones or subsidiaries) between Marseille and Nice that offers unlimited mileage and allows to drive to Croatia ?

Comment: I'm surprised that an EU car rental agency can restrict you from driving to another EU country.  I've encountered situations where foreign travel was listed as restricted, but, after asking on the phone, I was told that it would on fact be possible to take the car abroad after asking for permission, whereupon the agency gave me the necessary insurance papers.  Sometimes they charge for this.  Have you tried asking anyone by phone or e-mail, or are you basing your question on information shown in the general terms and conditions or elsewhere on the company's website?

Comment: This is not a price shopping question; it is an "is it possible" question.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: I have rented cars from Hertz several times and the only limit I have had was to go outside the EU zone, not to another country. So in the case of my rentals, they were ok for me to go to Northern Ireland and back to Ireland.

Comment: (+1) I posted an answer about Avis, because they do seem to allow driving to Croatia and usually have unlimited mileage in my experience but looking for a car in Nice, I do see a mileage restriction so I deleted the answer… From the car hire agencies you checked, which ones offer unlimited mileage but forbid Croatia?

Comment: @Relaxed Hertz gives you unlimited mileage but forbids Croatia. In fact: "Hertz vehicles may only be taken in the following countries: Andorra, Austria, Belgium, Denmark, Finland, Germany, Gibraltar, Ireland, Italy, Liechtenstein, Luxembourg, Monaco, Netherlands, Norway, Portugal, San Marino, Spain (not including the Spanish enclaves of Ceuta and Melilla), Sweden, Switzerland and the United Kingdom (including Northern Ireland)". [Source](https://www.hertz.fr/rentacar/reservation/reviewmodifycancel/templates/rentalTerms.jsp?KEYWORD=DRIVINGRESTRICTIONS&EOAG=PARS65)

Comment: Highly unlikely, Croatia is one of 'high risk' countries. If you really need to drive such high distances, consider buying own car. Otherwise flight would make more sense on such distance.

Comment: I checked with local car-rentals and all of them gave me a no-go for Croatia and unlimited mileage at the same time. The main reason (after some digging) is that they are sure to lose money since there is a greater risk that I drive a lot, and that the car loses value way faster than if I just drove to the Netherlands or Germany (ca. 3 000 km vs 4 000+ km) for the same rental fee. 
I managed to rent a car from a private person via a website, and then negociated with him to pay a small fee (7 cents per exceeded kilometer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked with local car-rentals and all of them gave me a no-go for Croatia and unlimited mileage at the same time. The main reason (after some digging) is that they are sure to lose money since there is a greater *risk* that I drive a lot, and that the car loses value way faster than if I drove to the Netherlands or Germany (ca. 3 000 km vs 4 000+ km) for the same rental fee.
When they don't allow to drive in a country, either it's explicitly written in the car's documents and you just can't pass the border controls, either the car rental insurance is void and you're on your own in case of an accident. But I ***don't*** recommend trying this.

I managed to rent a car from a private person via a website, paid for my estimated mileage, and then negotiated with him to pay a small fee in case I drive more (7 cents per exceeded kilometer).

Comment: (+1) Interesting although the explanation does not fully makes sense to me: It would seem to rule out unlimited mileage in general and yet some car hire companies do offer it. Incidentally, I usually rent from Avis in the Netherlands and they do offer unlimited mileage by default and explicitly allow you to drive all the way to Croatia or Portugal, a much longer distance than from the south of France (which is why I was surprised they did not offer the same conditions in France). In fact, from Nice, Croatia is closer than Berlin.

Comment: From now on I'm just guessing: marketing wise, it's good to offer unlimited mileage, and maybe they found out that not _that_ many people are actually driving to Berlin and more would like to drive to Croatia. As pointed out in some comments, those limitations change from country to country, and even maybe from subsidiary to subsidiary. But again, it's just a guess.
Next time I rent a car for such travels, I'll go deeper into researching what can be negotiated, but for this travel time was a bit short.